# history.js and iFrame - Refresh Case

Tags: javascript, refresh, back-button, browser-history, history.js

I'm trying to manage the state of a page, which contains several iFrames. What I'm trying to achieve are as follow:

1) When refreshing parent page, the content in iFrames should stay in the same state (a good example is a Facebook iFrame app use case)

2) When clicking Back button, only the content of one of the iFrames go back 1 page/step in the history

The iFrames consist of both client-side rendering only pages, server-side rendering only pages (including static HTML), and mixed.

Is there an easy way to do this? I tried using history.js, but when I refresh the page, it goes back to the first page that the iFrame was loaded with. I'm assuming that I'm not using it right, but the documentation is also not very easy to follow.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Since the src of the frame is set by the parent window, I'm guessing that history.js will not be much of a help here. I will probably use postMessage to publish the state to parent window and centrally manage it for all iFrames. Another possibility is to manage it on server side, but I had to rule that out since our goal is to not have to rely on server side. Let me know if you have a better idea.